# cannot find symbol method getJSONArray(String) Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

hi everyone i am working on a android project where i have to retrive the data form JSON. here is my [link](http://52.89.46.93/communityApp/?methodName=get.person&person_id=9)

I am trying to get the data using the below code

```html
public class DisplayUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textViewResult;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_user);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check_data_id); // in this text view i will display the text

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);


        String url = statics_demo.USER_URL+"7";// this is fixed url where i am getting the data
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(DisplayUser.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    JSONObject result;
    private void showJSON(String response) {

        try {
            JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("responseMs");

            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                System.out.println("luckyyyyyy"+name);
              //  String type = jsonObject.getString("type");

                // retrieve the values like this so on..

            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

When i run the code i am getting a erorr saying 
**"Error:(60, 37) error: cannot find symbol method getJSONArray(String)"**

Comment: JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("responseMs");    I think you meant JSONObject obj.

Comment: I need to get the array data but getJSONArray not acepting array object as string.

Comment: Sorry I misread your code.  Look what the type of response is.  Its a string.  If you want to get a JSONArray out of it, you first have to create a JSONObject from it.

Answer (score -1):

### String s = "[]"; JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); JsonElement tradeElement = parser.parse(s); JsonArray trade = tradeElement.getAsJsonArray();

---

you need to convert string to jsonarray first

Comment: At  least he will get the idea what he is missing out and can change according to his classes.@Selvin,Also downvoting is not an art

Comment: No, as he doesn't understand that String has no such method like getJSONArray

Comment: May be he is learning ,error can be done by anyone.NO one is perfect